# CakePHP adding a comment to Photo

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem with adding comments to photos on my website. In comments table I have:
`id`, `user_id`, `photo_id`, `content`, `created`, `modified`, `erased`.

In view I create:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Comment');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('content');
echo $this->Form->input($this->Session->read('User.id'), array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input($photo['Photo']['id'], array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add comment');
```

I don't know if it is correct way. How cake will know that 2 hidden values are `user_id` and `photo_id` ?

Thx for advices.

Comment: If you do it correctly and have the model associations set up correctly, Cake knows that user_id and photo_id are hidden because they're foreign keys. However, you're using `FormHelper::input()` incorrectly, so Cake won't know what those two inputs are supposed to be.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to populate User ID in the controller when the data is submitted (so users cannot post as other users). You can fetch the user ID with `$this->Auth->user('id');` (providing you are using the built in Auth component). As for photo ID, you obviously have this somewhere as you're loading the photo, you just need to pass this data into `$this->request->data` before you save.

A simple CakePHP 2 approach would be like so:

```
public function viewPhoto($photoId) { //$photoId comes from your routes or something

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Comment']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->request->data['Comment']['photo_id'] = $photoId;
        $this->Photo->Comment->save($this->request->data);
    }

}
```

This structure be slightly different for you, depending on your controller/model setup.

Comment: it is better to not add hidden values to the forms (especially without security component active) but to add those values in the controller prior to the save() call.

Comment: it was a comment mainly for the creator of the question - since you did not explicitly note the security component as a requirement I thought it would be good to add this :) but yes, your code states this.